# Getting PointCloud2 data in Python?

Tags: python, kinect, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to translate the TurtleBot "follower" program (written in C++) to
Python but I'm not sure how to read the (x, y, z) values from the PointCloud2 message returned by the Kinect without using PCL. I know I can use the depth **image** from the Kinect on /camera/depth/image but I'd rather use the PointCloud2 message type if possible.

I can subscribe to the /camera/depth/points or /camera/rgb/points topic and print back things like the message header and field names, but I'm not sure how to get the actual x, y and z data values so that I can iterate through them and compute average values.  Does anyone know the magic incantation?

Thanks!
patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35655/getting-pointcloud2-data-in-python?/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2012-06-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apparently this functionality is a part of sensor_msgs package, here's a [link to  relevant file](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/browser/stacks/common_msgs/trunk/sensor_msgs/src/sensor_msgs/point_cloud2.py?rev=38643).

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2012-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2012-06-04**:
Thanks @arebgun.  I'm wondering if this has made it into the Electric debs yet?  I grabbed the source for sensor_msgs from trunk and although it compiled fine, I can't seem to use it in my follower package.  When doing a rosmake I get "Package sensor_msgs was not found in the pkg-config search path"

**Comment by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on 2012-06-04**:
It doesn't look like this file is in the electric tree. The file is 4 months old, so I doubt that electric will have that functionality at all. 1.7.x and later series of the stack have this python file, so Fuerte should have this, but not Electric (1.6.x. series).